# How to set a new password from bash?

Tags: linux, bash, password, pipe

I'm using busybox with a limited passwd (I don't have --stdin option) and without `chpasswd` and I need to change the password of an user from bash. Here is my best result:

```
echo newpassword > pwdfile
echo newpassword > pwdfile
cat pwdfile | passwd myuser
Changing password for myuser
Enter the new password (minimum of 5, maximum of 8 characters)
Please use a combination of upper and lower case letters and numbers.
Enter new password:
Bad password: too simple.

Warning: weak password (continuing).
Re-enter new password:
passwd: The password for myuser is unchanged.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Busybox has `chpasswd(8)` which is a utility best used to create/update a lot of users very quickly and with one command. It accepts data from `STDIN` in `username:password` form. That means that you can do something like this:

```
$ cat pwdfile | chpasswd
```

or

```
$ < pwdfile chpasswd
```

Note that `pwdfile` must have `username:new_password` syntax.

Then again, you could always edit `/etc/shadow` yourself -- but please don't.

Comment: There's no need to cat to a pipe, just use IO redirection; `< pwdfile chpasswd`.

Comment: My busybox does not have chpasswd.

Comment: What is the output of `passwd --version`?

Comment: passwd: invalid option -- -
BusyBox v1.00 (2011.04.28-16:58+0000) multi-call binary

Usage: passwd [OPTION] [name]

Change a user password. If no name is specified,
changes the password for the current user.
Options:
        -a      Define which algorithm shall be used for the password
                        (Choices: des, md5)
        -d      Delete the password for the specified user account
        -l      Locks (disables) the specified user account
        -u      Unlocks (re-enables) the specified user account

Comment: Is the user you're changing the password for in both `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`?

Comment: Yes, it is present on both files. The user can log in and out normally.

Comment: Can you try with a non-weak password? Maybe that's the issue.