# Create user from bash script

Tags: shell-script, useradd

I'm in the process of making a bash script to automate adding a user. My password always have pattern, so I am setting that to a variable then... (this is where I am stuck -encrypting-). I found [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52108/how-to-create-sha512-password-hashes-on-command-line) but that talks about `-stdin` which I don't want to use. Besides, I am asked for the password if I omit it anyway. So, how can I encrypt the password from my username automatically?

**My script**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 <user>"
else
  p=${1%.*}
  p=$(echo $p | tr -d 'aeiou' | openssl passwd) $1
  useradd -p $p $1
fi
```

EDIT: mkpasswd on CentOS doesn't seem to work like the one mentioned in the post I linked.

EDIT2: bash version is `4.1.2(1)-release`, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this, inspired from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26738/how-to-set-a-new-password-from-bash)

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 <user>"
else
  u=${2%.*}
  u=${u//[aeiou]}
  echo "$2:$u" > .tmp
  useradd $2
  < .tmp chpasswd
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `useradd` and `chpasswd` to automate user creation. e.g.

```
useradd -c "Bob Smith" -m bob
echo "bob:mypassword" | chpasswd
```

If you don't want the plain text password to appear in the script, use the `--encrypted` flag:

```
echo "bob:encrypted_mypassword" | chpasswd --encrypted
```

Comment: I have a pattern when creating the password, so I'd rather stick to that. With that said, maybe it's time to lose the pattern and use standard stuff.